# Динамическая загрузка DLL в C#/.NET

Tags: c#, .net, dll

Есть dll `System.Data.SQLite`, как мне сделать так что бы: при запуске программа докачивала эту dll, подключала и работала с ней.

Как бы в начале проекта я прописываю

```
using System.Data.SQLite;
```

но мне надо как то обойтись без этого ( ибо при этом способе мне нужно указывать ссылку в программе ) надеюсь понятно объяснил)))

Comment: Ради чего всё это?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Самый простой вариант это так:

```
var dll = Assembly.LoadFrom("http://example.com/test.dll");
```

Так же Вам может помочь [ClickOnce](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/t71a733d(v=vs.100).aspx)

Так же можно попробовать так:
Дописать в конфиг поиск dll в интернете:

```
<configuration>
<runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
     <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="test" publicKeyToken="xxxxxxxxxxx" culture="neutral" />          
        <codeBase version="x.x.x.x" href="http://example.com/test.dll"/>
     </dependentAssembly>
  </assemblyBinding>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, тут появился другой казус, как сделать приложение AnyCPU? я работаю с библиотекой SQLite но у нее 2 версии 64 и 86 иксовая....как мне подключить библиотеку в зависимости от разрядности?

Comment: @Corle, `Solution Properties -> ConfigurationsMgr`