# Почему возникает ошибка при загрузке DLL-файла?

Tags: c#, dll, веб-сервер

При попытке загрузить файл с хоста таким образом

```
var a = Assembly.LoadFrom("http://example.com/ConsoleClient.dll");
```

Возникает следующая ошибка:
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: "Не удалось загрузить файл или сборку "http://example.com/ConsoleClient.dll" либо одну из их зависимостей. Не удается найти указанный файл."

Хотя на хосте файл присутствует, и, перейдя по той же ссылке через браузер, я могу скачать библиотеку. 
Подскажите, в чем проблема?

Comment: Потому что вы путаете путь до файла и URL до загрузки файла.

Comment: Скачайте файл при помощи классов для работы с HTTP, а потом уже загружайте его

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Я взял этот пример отсюда https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/443983/%D0%94%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0-dll-%D0%B2-c-net В случае, если инфа неверная, то как я могу это реализовать?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ А можно ли как-то сделать это без скачивания на диск? То есть, чтобы библиотека находилась в оперативной памяти

Comment: Можно без скачивания на диск, ищите перегрузки `Load`/`LoadFrom` которые принимают на вход `Stream` или массив байт.

Comment: @Zergatul Нашел, есть такой. Спасибо!

Comment: Загрузка просто указанием url, как  вопросе, должна работать и без ручного скачивания, если у вызывающего кода хватает прав. Стоит посмотреть детали исключения и InnerException - так скорее всего будет реальная ошибка.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Начиная с .net 4.0 загрузка кода из удаленных источников [запрещена по умолчанию](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/loadfromremotesources-element)

При попытке загрузить бросается исключение

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'file:assem.dll' or one of its dependencies. Operation is not supported. 
(Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131515)
File name: 'file:assem.dll' ---> 
System.NotSupportedException: An attempt was made to load an assembly from a network location which would have caused the assembly 
to be sandboxed in previous versions of the .NET Framework. This release of the .NET Framework does not enable CAS policy by default, 
so this load may be dangerous. If this load is not intended to sandbox the assembly, please enable the loadFromRemoteSources switch.
```

Можно включить старое поведение через элемент loadFromRemoteSources в app.config.